# Помогите с форматированием данных для Highcharts

Tags: php, javascript, mysqli, highcharts

Здравствуйте. Есть таблица MySQL примерно такого вида:

```
Пол        Позиция     Возраст    Возрастная группа
Женщина    За          25         18-25
Мужчина    За          27         25-40
```

Ну и т.д. Так же есть PHP файл, который с помощью mysqli запроса

```
SELECT      `Позиция`,`Возрастная группа`, count(*)
FROM          `Люди`
WHERE `Позиция` IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY `Позиция`, `Возрастная группа`
```

вытягивает данные и создаёт из них массив, который переходит в json_encode. К этому файлу как к источнику данных обращается Highcharts с такими настройками

```
 <script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var options = {
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        type: 'column',
                        marginRight: 130,
                        marginBottom: 25
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Какое-то название',
                        x: -20 //center
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: '',
                        x: -20
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: []
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Какое-то название'
                        },
                        plotLines: [{
                            value: 0,
                            width: 1,
                            color: '#808080'
                        }]
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                                this.x +': '+ this.y;
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        x: -10,
                        y: 100,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        column: {
                            stacking: 'normal',
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                color: (Highcharts.theme Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    series: []
                }

                $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
                    options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
                    options.series[0].data = json[1];
                    options.series[1] = json[2];
                    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                });
            });
    </script>
```

Вопрос. Как мне изменить настройку series или как построить запрос так, чтобы форматирование данных подошло и график построился? Хочу Highcharts Stacked Column Chart.

UPD: JSON выглядит примерно вот так:

```
array (
0 => 
array (
0 => 'Сторонник',
1 => '18-25',
2 => 15,
),
1 => 
array (
0 => 'Сторонник',
1 => '26-40',
2 => 436,
),
2 => 
array (
0 => 'Сторонник',
1 => '41-55',
2 => 632,
),
3 => 
array (
0 => 'Сторонник',
1 => '56+',
2 => 2149,
),
4 => 
array (
0 => 'Противник',
1 => '18-25',
2 => 30,
),
5 => 
array (
0 => 'Противник',
1 => '26-40',
2 => 653,
),
6 => 
array (
0 => 'Противник',
1 => '41-55',
2 => 876,
),
7 => 
array (
0 => 'Противник',
1 => '56+',
2 => 3014,
),
8 => 
array (
0 => 'Потенциальный сторонник',
1 => '18-25',
2 => 9,
),
9 => 
array (
0 => 'Потенциальный сторонник',
1 => '26-40',
2 => 170,
),
10 => 
array (
0 => 'Потенциальный сторонник',
1 => '41-55',
2 => 280,
),
11 => 
array (
0 => 'Потенциальный сторонник',
1 => '56+',
2 => 992,
),
12 => 
array (
0 => 'Не определился',
1 => '18-25',
2 => 44,
),
13 => 
array (
0 => 'Не определился',
1 => '26-40',
2 => 862,
),
14 => 
array (
0 => 'Не определился',
1 => '41-55',
2 => 1266,
),
15 => 
array (
0 => 'Не определился',
1 => '56+',
2 => 3656,
),
)
```

То, что достаёт данные из MySQL

```
$result = mysqli_query ($con, $sql);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$row[0] = $r[0];
$row[1] = $r[1];
array_push($rows,$row);
}

print json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: вы приведите пример желаемого графика то в виде картинки что ли. и полученного json. в данном случае то как данные выглядят в базе и вытаскиваются вообще не интересно

Comment: ну так сами форматирование данных и сделайте таким, каким оно требуется графику. А чтобы понять каким оно должно быть, прочтите доки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 минуты гугления выкинуло меня в документацию, в документации нашел [примерный график](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-basic/), согласно которому забадяжил данный кодик.

```
//ваш массив
$arr = [
    0  => [
        0 => 'Сторонник',
        1 => '18-25',
        2 => 15,
    ],
    1  => [
        0 => 'Сторонник',
        1 => '26-40',
        2 => 436,
    ],
    2  => [
        0 => 'Сторонник',
        1 => '41-55',
        2 => 632,
    ],
    3  => [
        0 => 'Сторонник',
        1 => '56+',
        2 => 2149,
    ],
    4  => [
        0 => 'Противник',
        1 => '18-25',
        2 => 30,
    ],
    5  => [
        0 => 'Противник',
        1 => '26-40',
        2 => 653,
    ],
    6  => [
        0 => 'Противник',
        1 => '41-55',
        2 => 876,
    ],
    7  => [
        0 => 'Противник',
        1 => '56+',
        2 => 3014,
    ],
    8  => [
        0 => 'Потенциальный сторонник',
        1 => '18-25',
        2 => 9,
    ],
    9  => [
        0 => 'Потенциальный сторонник',
        1 => '26-40',
        2 => 170,
    ],
    10 => [
        0 => 'Потенциальный сторонник',
        1 => '41-55',
        2 => 280,
    ],
    11 => [
        0 => 'Потенциальный сторонник',
        1 => '56+',
        2 => 992,
    ],
    12 => [
        0 => 'Не определился',
        1 => '18-25',
        2 => 44,
    ],
    13 => [
        0 => 'Не определился',
        1 => '26-40',
        2 => 862,
    ],
    14 => [
        0 => 'Не определился',
        1 => '41-55',
        2 => 1266,
    ],
    15 => [
        0 => 'Не определился',
        1 => '56+',
        2 => 3656,
    ],
];

//названия выводятся справа
$right = [];

//числовые данные графика
$data = [];
foreach ($arr as $index => $value) {

    if (!in_array($value[1], $right)) $right[] = $value[1];

    if (!isset($data[$value[0]])) {
        $data[$value[0]] = ['name' => $value[0]];
        $data[$value[0]]['data'][] = $value[2];
    } else {
        $data[$value[0]]['data'][] = $value[2];
    }

}

//заполняем массив, из которого будет создан json
$new_arr['names'] = $right;
$new_arr['data'] = $data;

//убираю ассоц. ключи из массива
foreach ($new_arr['data'] as $index => $value) {
    $without_assoc[] = $value;
}
$new_arr['data'] = $without_assoc;

//выводим json
echo json_encode($new_arr);
```

Далее копирую json в html.

В пхп-массиве `names` и `data` я назвал как захотел, чтобы позже обратиться к ним в яваскрипте

```
  options.xAxis.categories = json.names;
  options.series = json.data;
```

А вот внутри data - name и data изменять нельзя, так как к ним обращается ядро хайхчарта.

`plotOptions` вычеркнул, так как эта секция дает ошибку в строке

```
 color: (Highcharts.theme Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>titile</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>

  </style>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var options = {
        chart: {
          renderTo: 'container',
          type: 'column',
          marginRight: 130,
          marginBottom: 25
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Название графика',
          x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
          text: '',
          x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: []
        },
        yAxis: {
          title: {
            text: 'Сбоку название'
          },
          plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
          }]
        },
        tooltip: {
          formatter: function() {
            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
              this.x + ': ' + this.y;
          }
        },
        legend: {
          layout: 'vertical',
          align: 'right',
          verticalAlign: 'top',
          x: -10,
          y: 100,
          borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: []
      }

      // $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {

      var json = {
        "names": ["18-25", "26-40", "41-55", "56+"],
        "data": [{
          "name": "\u0421\u0442\u043e\u0440\u043e\u043d\u043d\u0438\u043a",
          "data": [15, 436, 632, 2149]
        }, {
          "name": "\u041f\u0440\u043e\u0442\u0438\u0432\u043d\u0438\u043a",
          "data": [30, 653, 876, 3014]
        }, {
          "name": "\u041f\u043e\u0442\u0435\u043d\u0446\u0438\u0430\u043b\u044c\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u0441\u0442\u043e\u0440\u043e\u043d\u043d\u0438\u043a",
          "data": [9, 170, 280, 992]
        }, {
          "name": "\u041d\u0435 \u043e\u043f\u0440\u0435\u0434\u0435\u043b\u0438\u043b\u0441\u044f",
          "data": [44, 862, 1266, 3656]
        }]
      };

      options.xAxis.categories = json.names;
      options.series = json.data;

      chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
      // });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>


  <div id="container"></div>
  <div class="container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Про ту строку - там просто && почему-то не скопировалось. Вопрос как раз был в том, как мне сформировать нужный массив и в последствии JSON. JSON и точные действия сейчас уточню в вопросе.

Comment: Мне просто нужен конкретный метод, как из того, что я получил (JSON) мне сделать JSON, который подойдёт под график, т.е мне надо его как-то модифицировать, а я не знаю, как на PHP\JS это делается

Comment: @ПавелНасевич обновил ответ.

Comment: Я вам очень благодарен. Добавил PlotOptions (у меня там всё правильно, просто на Overflow показалось криво), там настроил Stacking, получилось именно так, как хотел. Сейчас буду разбираться!

Comment: Эх... Получаю 1:1 данные со скрипта, что и в статичном JSON, как в примере. Но при этом с статики отрисовывает, а с полученного от PHP - нет. Появляются категории, легенда, но самих столбцов, как и мерной шкалы слева нету.

Comment: Хорошо, что валялся старый бук с Beyond Compare - он подсказал, что по вашему скрипту данные строковые, а в статичном JSON - цифровые. Как пофиксить спрашивать не буду, ибо Google. Спасибо!

Comment: Неправильно работает ваш код. В data[0] есть все 4 категории, а дальше data[1] и т.д только 3 категории. В итоге на highcharts в категории 56+ только противники. Что могло пойти не так? Код 1:1 такой-же, только поставил intval, но без него та же фигня.